# Fastest data parsing from database

Tags: database, rows, nosql

I have about 10.000 different people, generating about 25.000 data (position and other data types) each day.
I need to take all these data for a week... so that is about 10.000 * 3.000 * 7 = 210 millions of data.

Then I need to manage that data, clustering, filtering, etc ...

Question is: what is the best way to store it ? I guess nosql like mongo.
What is the best (fastest) language to parse it ?  node would do it ? php ?

The output will go to a Leaflet map.

I guess a (paid) solution is Carto, but I'd like to think about doing by myselfin first place.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) to store and [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) to process... a good place to start is [here](https://academy.datastax.com/courses) with lots of info for free